# How to insert \bigstar in section title with same baseline?

Tags: symbols, amssymb, baseline

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
STAR$\bigstar$METHODS
\end{document}
```

[image: The baseline of the bigstar is lower than text]

Aim:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem is that the bounding box of `\bigstar` is a bit deeper than the actual glyph. On the other hand, `pifont` provides the correctly sized symbol.

With `\DeclareRobustCommand` you make the command safe for section titles.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\textbigstar}{\mbox{\ding{72}}}

\begin{document}

STAR\textbigstar METHODS

\bigskip

\Large
STAR\textbigstar METHODS

\end{document}
```

[image]

With rules to show the baseline and the top:

[image]

With `hyperref` (thanks to Phelype Oleinik for suggesting):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\textbigstar}{\texorpdfstring{\mbox{\ding{72}}}{★}}

\begin{document}

\section{STAR\textbigstar METHODS}

STAR\textbigstar METHODS

\bigskip

\Large
STAR\textbigstar METHODS

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Clean, tidy and excellent answer! Even just `\ding{72}` is ok for section title.

Comment: A small issue with this is that the star does not show in pdf index(generated by package hyperref). @edreg

Comment: @Zuooo You can use the unicode symbol in the PDF bookmark. Try `\section{Star \texorpdfstring{\textbigstar}{★} methods}`. You also need to pass the `unicode` option to `hyperref`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks, but it still does not show in pdf index.

Comment: @Zuooo Did you pass the `unicode` option to `hyperref`?

Comment: @Zuooo I'm very little child than to the great user :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here there is my proposal using the macro `\basestar` and by comment of the user @Zuooo I have scaling the symbol `\bigstar` with `scalerel` package. You can increase or decrease the star with the scale factor `.7` into `\scaleobj`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\basestar{\ensuremath{\mathrel{\raisebox{1pt}{\scaleobj{.7}{\bigstar}}}}} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\textcolor{brown}{STAR$\basestar$METHODS}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can see the upperline is higher than text. Maybe by resize?

Comment: Excuse me very much. But do you want a small star?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you can see the "Aim" picture from the question, I want that star... haha

Comment: `\raisebox{\dimexpr0.5\height - \fontdimen 22\textfont 2}` would not depend on the font size.

Comment: @Bernard Kind Bernard I have given my version :-). You are free to change my MWE if you think so. The best users always take precedence as I wrote three years ago when I have been registered on TeX.SE.

Comment: @Sebastiano Why it shows error when put $\basestar$ into section title? $\bigstar$ will not.

Comment: @Bernard Do you mean `\def\newstar{\ensuremath{\mathrel{\raisebox{\dimexpr0.5\height - \fontdimen 22\textfont 2}{\scaleobj{.8}{\bigstar}}}}} ` it doesn't work.

Comment: I just meant `\raisebox{\dimexpr0.5\height - \fontdimen 22\textfont 2}{$\bigstar$}`.

Comment: Thanks, @Bernard. But it still need to be resized to mach both top and bottom baseline with text, right?

Comment: I didn't test, but `\scalebox{0.8}{$\bigstar$}`  as an argument of `\raisebox` should work.

Comment: @Bernard This does not work: `\raisebox{\dimexpr0.5\height - \fontdimen 22\textfont 2}\scalebox{0.8}{$\bigstar$}`

Comment: If you wanner give a hand, you can post an answer, as all efforts seems not work in section title.

Comment: Please see my answer: in case of a `\scalebox` I use \depth`, not 0.5\height`. There remains a (very) small difference (less than 0.1pt).

Answer (score 4):

Here is another method:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\textsf{\color{Maroon} STAR \raisebox{\dimexpr\fontdimen 22\textfont 2-\depth}{\scalebox{0.8}{$\bigstar$}} METHODS}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! @Bernard

Comment: I have seen :-)...now...